# PL/SQL column mask with fixed number of characters in queries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, mask

I'd like to write a query so its output would be a well formated text. Each of its columns would be a specific number of characters wide, if the column's value returned by the query is smaller then the columns number of characters, the remaining characters would be informed as "0" if the column represents a number or " " if the column represents a string. Is it possible?

Thanks,

Thiago

Comment: Personally, I would handle display/formatting issues like this in the presentation layer, not in the database.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - Agreed.  Attempting to format stuff in the database is the root of all kinds of evil.  That way lies madness, with things like multi-value columns.

Comment: sounds like old school report formatting.  How about output delimited file (csv) and open in Excel?  Just a thought.  Management loves their Excel ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the experts have warned you against it, but here it is:

```
select   case when REGEXP_replace (DUMP (varchar2_column), '^Typ=(\d+).*', '\1') = 1 then lpad(varchar2_column, 10, ' ')
          else null end varchar2_column,
         case when REGEXP_replace (DUMP (number_column), '^Typ=(\d+).*', '\1') = 2 then lpad(number_column, 10, 0)
          else null end number_column
  from   table
```

data types (from dump):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG

oracle regular expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

I would post the link for the dump function, but my reputation, is, well... You can Google it.